# Under Construction displaying in Site after updating VF functionality

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a small Site that has been deployed for a year or so with read/write access to a single custom object.  I recently added a new field to the object and one of the VF pages, and modified the behavior of the page to be more responsive.  I granted access to the field to the Guest User profile and the page works fine from apex/pageName when I do my initial testing.

Visitors are directed to the site via email/sms links that we send out.

The updated page is not the initial landing page [InventoryPortalWelcome, as indicated below]; I do some validation of the URL parameters first, and if they're in good order the visitor is redirected to the updated page.  When I test the email links from the sandbox, however, the site displays the 'Under Construction' page instead.  The Site page (screenshot) below is from the sandbox.

Where do I look to determine what's preventing the updated Site from performing/appearing correctly?

[image: Site settings:]

Comment: What happens when you visit the `VisualForce Page` outside the `Site` context?

Comment: The new page loads correctly - InventoryPortalWelcome does not display anything; it's only purpose is validation, and then the updated page/form loads.  Hmm ... I have been accessing the updated page directly, not going to the validation page first -- I'll do that now.

Comment: That's my story and I'm sticking to it -- referencing apex/InventoryPortalWelcome?pi=parameter does the validation and displays correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the `Site` can access whatever page you redirect to? Maybe it's permissions got messed up somehow.

Comment: The page is listed in the Site VisualForce Pages list; nothing changed there.

Comment: I also double-checked the Guest User profile - listed there, too.

Comment: Try configuring a debug log for the Guest User, see if the VF page is throwing an error.

Comment: My error (well, my code's error, technically...); left out the Path in the URL.  But it is Friday!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I added a toggle in my email/SMS code based on whether we're in the sandbox or not, and in the sandbox URL I had the Site location right, but left out the Path.  *Not sure why, since it's right there on the Production branch of the IF() statement...*

Just goes to show me for allowing my customers to make changes...  Thanks Adrian, Jason for responding so quickly!